# Qmake Headers Library

Tags: c++, qt-creator, qmake

I create qmake project with "Subdirs" template, header library and testing console-application.

**Main.pro**:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt
CONFIG += ordered

SUBDIRS += tests Config
```

**Config.pro**:

```
HEADERS +=  \
Reader.h \
Builder.h\
Store.h\
Setter.h
```

**tests.pro**:

```
HEADERS += \
CheckConfig.h \
CheckReader.h \
JsonGenerator.h \
Setter.h

SOURCES += \
CheckReader.cpp \
JsonGenerator.cpp \
main.cpp \
Setter.cpp

#my util functions and vars
include(../common/settings.pri)
include(../common/common.pri)

#generate application config
ConsoleApplication(test)
#enable flags for exports libs in depends.pri file
EnableModuleExport()
include(../Config/depends.pri)
#setup includepath for Config library
SetHeadersPath(../)
```

qmake generate makefile for project Config.pro, after run build with gcc, I have error. That's okay, because I did not ask the build targets and no function main(). It is necessary to disable the generation of a Makefile for qmake, or generate a makefile without build targets.

I did the project Config as fake static library, but it is not the best solution

Comment: I'm sorry not to understand your question...

Comment: Well, I'll try to reformulate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Headear-only library need use requires(false)

```
HEADERS += <your headers files>
#needed in QtCreator for correct display "#include" directives
INCLUDEPATH += <your deps> 
requires(false) #disable building
```

Answer (score 0):

@Kopysov Evgeniy
requires(false) prevents the install target from running too! Header only libraries still need to be installed.

Comment: Discovered by experimenting, that requires(false) does not work, but you need a TEMPLATE and a TARGET line

Answer (score 0):

Comment system not working for me, so one needs the following lines:

```
TEMPLATE=lib
LIB=dummy
HEADERS=...
headers.files=$$HEADERS
headers.path=$$PREFIX/include
INSTALLS+=headers
```